# Consuming Rest Web Service that returns XML via Javascript and/or PHP

Tags: javascript, xml, json, service

I have a web service I would like to consume with Javascript. I've tried reading all the documentation on Jquery to do this using JSONP, however I believe this is only for Web Services that return JSON data?

A few questions. I have a web service that returns XML, it's a Rest web service. Do I have to use an XML client or if I try to use a JSON client will it just "figure it out"?

Is there a way to return Cross Site web services via Jquery via javascript in XML? I can't seem to find an example anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery can load XML via ajax.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  Search for "dataType", there is an xml option.  I believe you can use jQuery selectors to pull data out of the XML.  I don't think there is a way to deserialize the XML to an object as part of jQuery, you'll need to extract the XML information manually.